# HTTP Headers for File Downloads

Tags: php, http-headers, download, content-type

I've written a PHP script that handles file downloads, determining which file is being requested and setting the proper HTTP headers to trigger the browser to actually download the file (rather than displaying it in the browser).

I now have a problem where some users have reported certain files being identified incorrectly (so regardless of extension, the browser will consider it a GIF image). I'm guessing this is because I haven't set the "Content-type" in the response header. Is this most likely the case? If so, is there a fairly generic type that could be used for all files, rather than trying to account for every possible file type?

Currently I'm only setting the value "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=arandomf.ile"

**Update:** I followed this guide here to build a more robust process for file downloads (http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/12/how-to-force-file-download-with-php/), but there is a significant delay between when the script is executed and when the browser's download dialog appears. Can anyone identify the bottleneck that is causing this?

Here's my implementation:

```
/**
 * Outputs the specified file to the browser.
 *
 * @param string $filePath the path to the file to output
 * @param string $fileName the name of the file
 * @param string $mimeType the type of file
 */
function outputFile($filePath, $fileName, $mimeType = '') {
    // Setup
    $mimeTypes = array(
        'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
        'txt' => 'text/plain',
        'html' => 'text/html',
        'exe' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'zip' => 'application/zip',
        'doc' => 'application/msword',
        'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'ppt' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'jpeg' => 'image/jpg',
        'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
        'php' => 'text/plain'
    );
    
    $fileSize = filesize($filePath);
    $fileName = rawurldecode($fileName);
    $fileExt = '';
    
    // Determine MIME Type
    if($mimeType == '') {
        $fileExt = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filePath, '.'), 1));
        
        if(array_key_exists($fileExt, $mimeTypes)) {
            $mimeType = $mimeTypes[$fileExt];
        }
        else {
            $mimeType = 'application/force-download';
        }
    }
    
    // Disable Output Buffering
    @ob_end_clean();
    
    // IE Required
    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
    }
    
    // Send Headers
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mimeType);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    
    // Send Headers: Prevent Caching of File
    header('Cache-Control: private');
    header('Pragma: private');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    
    // Multipart-Download and Download Resuming Support
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        list($a, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        list($range) = explode(',', $range, 2);
        list($range, $rangeEnd) = explode('-', $range);
        
        $range = intval($range);
        
        if(!$rangeEnd) {
            $rangeEnd = $fileSize - 1;
        }
        else {
            $rangeEnd = intval($rangeEnd);
        }
        
        $newLength = $rangeEnd - $range + 1;
        
        // Send Headers
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header('Content-Length: ' . $newLength);
        header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $range - $rangeEnd / $fileSize);
    }
    else {
        $newLength = $fileSize;
        header('Content-Length: ' . $fileSize);
    }
    
    // Output File
    $chunkSize = 1 * (1024*1024);
    $bytesSend = 0;
    
    if($file = fopen($filePath, 'r')) {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
            fseek($file, $range);
            
            while(!feof($file) && !connection_aborted() && $bytesSend < $newLength) {
                $buffer = fread($file, $chunkSize);
                echo $buffer;
                flush();
                $bytesSend += strlen($buffer);
            }
            
            fclose($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946612/php-download-script-outputs-corrupted-file

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Acoording to [RFC 2046 (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions)](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt):

> The recommended action for an
>   implementation that receives an
>   "application/octet-stream" entity is
>   to simply offer to put the data    in
>   a file

So I'd go for that one.

Comment: I agree - application/octet-stream tells the browser that it's a generic binary file which will cause it to save to disk

Comment: But `Content-disposition` is more correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download

Answer (score 75):

As explained by Alex's link you're probably missing the header `Content-Disposition` on top of `Content-Type`.

So something like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="MyFileName.ext"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try this [force-download script](http://elouai.com/force-download.php). Even if you don't use it, it'll probably point you in the right direction:

```
<?php

$filename = $_GET['file'];

// required for IE, otherwise Content-disposition is ignored
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

// addition by Jorg Weske
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

if( $filename == "" ) 
{
  echo "<html><title>eLouai's Download Script</title><body>ERROR: download file NOT SPECIFIED. USE force-download.php?file=filepath</body></html>";
  exit;
} elseif ( ! file_exists( $filename ) ) 
{
  echo "<html><title>eLouai's Download Script</title><body>ERROR: File not found. USE force-download.php?file=filepath</body></html>";
  exit;
};
switch( $file_extension )
{
  case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
  case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
  case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
  case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
  case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
  case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
  case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
  case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
  case "jpeg":
  case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
  default: $ctype="application/octet-stream";
}
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
// change, added quotes to allow spaces in filenames, by Rajkumar Singh
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile("$filename");
exit();
```

Comment: Note that ````Content-Type: application/force-download```` and ````Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary```` are not HTTP standards. They might work, but are useless here. RFC2616: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17

Comment: "application/force-download" is not the best default; "application/octet-stream" would be better

Answer (score 0):

less code and some security improvements

```
    <?php

$filename = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'file'); // recommended solution replaced by MalcolmX

// required for IE, otherwise Content-disposition is ignored
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

if(!file_exists($filename)) 
{
  echo "<script>alert('File is not available, check file name');</script>";
}; // filename empty doesn't exist too - MalcolX

// theres mimetype implemented in PHP - MalcolmX
$ctype= mime_content_type($filename);
}
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
// change, added quotes to allow spaces in filenames, by Rajkumar Singh
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile($filename); // and ofcourse quotes not necessary
exit();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).