# Replace %20 with spaces when downloading files?

Tags: php, replace, filenames, download

Is it possible to get a url/downloaded file name change the "%20" to spaces? Like instead of downloading the file *my%20file.pdf*, download *my file.pdf*? I'd like to use PHP if possible...

Comment: I just have to say I like the topic ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the `Content-Disposition` header to force a "Save As" dialog and recommend a file name like so:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my file.pdf"');
```

The [PHP.net page on `header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) seems to suggest the same.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to make use of the `Content-disposition` header.

Here's a [relevant answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386845/http-headers-for-file-downloads) Here's what the header might look like:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=my file.pdf
```

You could also use the reference for the [header() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Jinx indeed... you could have got the green tick just as easily so +1 to you :)