# createObjectURL overload resolution failed

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a PDF as a blob in JavaScript from the backend, but receive `Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed`. I'm not really sure where to go from here. I've looked at some of the other posts but none seem to deal with PDF, only audio.

The docs for `createObjectURL` say: "The new object URL represents the specified File object or Blob object", so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

From my backend, I set: `Content-type: application/octet-stream` then expect to be able to set the iFrame source, but it's not working.

I can verify that the blob data is in fact being returned from the backend.

This is the JS code that uses the blob.

```
iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
```

---

EDIT 1:

I'm being asked to edit my question with why the suggested prior post doesn't solve my issue. Here's a copy/paste from my comments below:

**I did see that post already and the accepted answer says: "Consider avoiding createObjectURL() method, while browsers are disabling support for it. Just attach MediaStream object directly to the srcObject property of HTMLMediaElement e.g.  element." I'm not an expert with JavaScript but I don't think MediaStream will work.**

---

EDIT 2:

Thanks to David Caldwell, in his comment he mentioned "src/srcObject"which made me look a little closer at the docs for MediaStream. I have something now that isn't erroring out. All I need is the correct Mime for the blob so I can use it in the iFrame src.

Here is what I have now that returns the srcObject:

```
var binaryData = [];
binaryData.push(data); //My blob
var foo = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/text"}));
console.log(foo); //gives me the correct object
```

Should I be using a Mime of "text"? I need to assign that object to the iFrame src.

---

EDIT3:

Using a MIME of `text/plain`, I get the following in the DOM:

```
<iframe id="iframe-target" src="blob:http://192.168.112.12/e25a4404-8233-44f0-86b3-1fff1109805f" width="100%" height="100%">
  #Document
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">[object Object]</pre> <--'object Object' is the issue
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

I now see the blob object in the iframe but the HTML within the iframe is showing as an Object. The object is actually a PDF but as it is, I can't view it. I still think this is a MIME issue, but I'm not sure what to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120757/failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url)

Comment: and if not, can you share the url to the pdf?

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell, Thanks David. I did see that post already and the accepted answer says: "Consider avoiding createObjectURL() method, while browsers are disabling support for it. Just attach MediaStream object directly to the srcObject property of HTMLMediaElement e.g. <video> element." I'm not an expert with JavaScript but I don't think MediaStream will work.

Comment: @ShanerM13, thanks for looking. The GET: `$.get("line.php", { 'cmd': "refresh", 'node': 'a' });`

Comment: Sounds good, @NaN -- I'd suggest rewording your question to make it clear that you don't know how to deal with `src`/`srcObject` when you're dealing with a PDF. (And search for duplicates on that, of course!). I don't know the answer, haven't used this API.

Comment: Are you creating a blob from your data? Please show how you populate the data variable shown here.

Comment: @TravisJ, pefect timing, Travis. I just posted up top. I think I am getting closer.

Comment: @NaN - I believe you want `{type: 'application/pdf'}` for your blob

Comment: @TravisJ, thanks. I tried `application/pdf` for type, but Chrome simply says "Failed to load PDF document." Still no joy here. :(

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467019/failed-to-load-pdf-document-in-chrome

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I've got a similar issue with a CSV Export containing large Strings in the blob which are throwing this error.

Comment: Check that the data passed to createObjectURL() is not null ```if(data){iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(data);}```

Comment: still no answers for it? I am trying to send the image buffer data to server and then to other client and when I try to convert it to a blob url it show me that error.

Comment: Check that data is not empty or null.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can still use `Content-type: application/pdf` on the response, the point is to receive a valid blob.

When creating the object URL, assuming `data` is still your blob, you should do:

```js
var blobObj = new Blob([atob(data)], { type: "application/pdf" });
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobObj);
document.getElementById("iframe-target").setAttribute("src", url);
```

Here, a few things are happening:

- `data` is converted back to binary with `atob()`
- this binary data is then passed as a byte array to the `Blob()` constructor
- the Blob object is used with the MIME type to create the object URL
- the resulting object URL can be used as the src attribute for an iframe

I've created a snippet as a small demo, here you can choose a local PDF file, which will be converted to base64, then used as the `src` attribute in an iframe. See the source code [on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/createobjecturl-from-pdf-eceim?file=/index.html) and [see the demo of the sandbox here](https://eceim.csb.app/).

---

**UPDATE:** Removed embedded snippet.

As [@K J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10802527/k-j) pointed out in the comments, running the snippet embedded or from the CodeSandbox editor will produce errors.

At first glance, it appears that the browser blocks the resulting blob URL. This is because `window.URL.createObjectURL` [prepends the blob URL differently based on the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377733/url-createobjecturl-returns-a-blob-with-null-prepended-eg-blobnull-12415-63).

This isn't a problem in production, but makes demoing the solution a bit more difficult. Luckily, CodeSandbox deploys the app to a host, where the blob URL scheme and host will match the app URL:
[image: blob URL matches the host]

In this case, the PDF will be shown as expected. I've tested [the deployed version of the sandbox](https://eceim.csb.app/) on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks @KJ for pointing this out, I've updated my answer to clarify why the snippet only works when deployed to a standalone host.