# FPDF Tutorial 1 returns "Error: Failed to load PDF document" in Chrome

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I've added FPDF to a PHP based web app I'm working on and I'm testing it out by following the tutorials on the FPDF website, but I'm running into an issue.

Here is the code that I'm working on, which is basically just a copy/paste of the first tutorial on the FPDF website:

```
require('../libs/fpdf182/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
```

When I run this, Chrome attempts to read the output, which suggests to me that FPDF is being loaded properly. However, I get the error "Failed to load PDF document". I've tried downloading the document and opening it in Microsoft Edge as well, but that also fails with a similar error message. It seems like the PDF document being generated is corrupted somehow, but I'm not sure how to fix this issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467019/failed-to-load-pdf-document-in-chrome

Comment: I've seen that link and that does appear to be similar to the issue I'm having. However, I'm not really sure what to do with the answers in that thread. The first answer describes an issue with web.config and points to an error in console to diagnose, but I'm not seeing that. The second answer claims the problem is solved at the source, but I'm still having it so this is apparently not true.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was some other code that I included but didn't mention. I was able to generate a readable pdf by reducing the code to literally just what was included above.