# How can I access debug information about why Google Chrome fails to load a PDF?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, pdf, pdfium

I have generated a PDF which loads correctly in Firefox, Okular, Evince, iOS Safari, and Adobe Reader, and also validates as PDF/A-3b in multiple PDF validators [here](https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx) and [here](https://www.pdfen.com/pdf-a-validator).

But it does not open in Chrome:

```
Error

Failed to load PDF document.
```

I'm aware of previous questions such as [Failed to load PDF document in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467019/failed-to-load-pdf-document-in-chrome), but the answers there do not help. This question is therefore not about my specific PDF, but about how to gain further information from Chrome that might help me debug the situation.

Comment: Do you open the pdf locally from the file system or remotely from some web service?

Comment: Locally and remotely both tested.

Comment: Can you share the pdf?

Comment: I’m sorry, I can not, but I’ll look into creating a sanitized shareable version.