# Download PDF from ReportViewer

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports

I have a "Download PDF" button that render a ReportViewer and open it in browser using Adobe Reader.
Here's the code:

```
Warning[] warn = null;
String[] streamids = null;
String mimeType = "application/pdf";
String encoding = String.Empty;
String extension = String.Empty;
Byte[] byteViewer;
byteViewer = report.LocalReport.Render("pdf", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warn);
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(byteViewer);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

But now, instead of opening the pdf, i want to open a download dialog to download the file. What changes in the code should I do?

@edit
The answers in that question are way too extensive, my question was asked to simplify the process of downloading a ReportViewer, and also adding a reference for future C# programmers that may encounter this question, without having to dig through lines of useless php code to find the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP Headers for File Downloads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386845/http-headers-for-file-downloads)

Comment: that dupe is for php, but the php is irrelevant. the headers are what matters.

Comment: you see in that question there's many lines of "header" code, if you could simply say which one solves my problem, that would be great...

Comment: nevermind, found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify the code for future StackOverflow users that may find this question:

in `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");`, just change `inline` to `attachment`, and that will download the file instead of opening in the browser.

*This answer is too simple, so I will check "community wiki" to be fair.*