# How to make auto download audio files in chrome instead of play it?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, autoplay

I've already disabled all plugins in Chrome.

In firefox we can go to `about:config` and set `media.play-stand-alone;false` `andplugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types;application/pdf,audio/mpeg`

How can we do this for Google Chrome?

Comment: Can you change the server to serve a different header? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/386863/2715716