# HTTP header file not downloaded completely

Tags: php, file, http, download, header

I am trying to download the file with **http header** but it will not download completly. The uploaded file `size is 1 MB` and the file download with my code `336 byte` size only.

I am  trying with below code

```
$attachment_location= "filename";
$filePath= "$siteURL/foldername/filename";
$file_content       = file_get_contents($filePath);
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$attachment_location\"");
echo $file_content;
```

Comment: That question may answer yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386845/http-headers-for-file-downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by just changing the **filepath** remove the path with `SiteURL` and provide the path from folder. Check code below,

```
$attachment_location= "filename";
$filePath= "foldername/filename";
$file_content       = file_get_contents($filePath);
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$attachment_location\"");
echo $file_content;
```