# Download automatically from a link on a website using Internet Explorer

Tags: html

A customer wants to download automatically the Pdf that is on a link on a webpage.

I manage to identify the link comparing the innertext with the one I want, the *href* points out to the Pdf File but I'm unable to save it automatically to the local disk without any action from the user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Headers for File Downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386845/http-headers-for-file-downloads)

Comment: I was working on attaching my CV as a pdf on my portfolio and I made it downloable on click on a pdf icon. This is what I used:   <a href="./images/Paulina.pdf" download="cv"><img class="cv" src="images/SVG/document-file-pdf.svg" alt="pdf"> </a>

Comment: The .pdf is not on my customer's site, it's an external from which we wants to download the file automatically to a certain folder.